# Target the parent element jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I am trying to apply certain classes with jQuery when in mobile view. Using Bootstrap and Font Awesome right now and when in mobile view the arrow down carrot turns into a plus sign that would be clickable to expand the dropdown menu. Right now when you click the + Font Awesome icon it will expand both dropdowns.

How can I make it so it applies to the dropdown pertaining to the + icon?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Google</a> <span class="fa fa-caret-down hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="fa visible-xs-inline pull-right fa-plus"></span> <span class="sr-only">Drop Down Indicator Icon</span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="http://smile.amazon.com">Amazon</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fake Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fake Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fake Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="http://smile.amazon.com" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Amazon</a> <span class="fa fa-caret-down hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="fa fa-plus visible-xs-inline pull-right"></span> <span class="sr-only">Drop Down Indicator Icon</span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fake Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fake Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fake Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the jQuery on the page I am currently using.

```
//Hover for the navigation. 
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown").hover(
    function(){ 
      $(this).addClass('open'); 
      $(".dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
    },
    function(){
      $(this).removeClass('open'); 
      $(".dropdown .dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
    }
  );
});

$('.dropdown-toggle').addClass("disabled");

//Add dropdown carrot to the dropdown items in menu. 
$("a.dropdown-toggle").after(" <span class='fa fa-caret-down hidden-xs' aria-hidden='true'></span><span class='fa fa-plus visible-xs-inline pull-right'></span> <span class='sr-only'>Drop Down Indicator Icon</span>");    
//Provides a way for the user to expand and collapse menu in mobile view. 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span.fa-plus").click(
    (function(e){
      if ($(".navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav li.dropdown").hasClass('menu-open')) {
        $(".navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav li.dropdown").removeClass('open');
        $(".navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav li.dropdown").removeClass('menu-open');
        $(".dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "true");  
        console.log("Top If");
      }
      else {
        $(".navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav li.dropdown").addClass('menu-open');
        $(".navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav li.dropdown").removeClass('open');
        $(".dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "false");  
        console.log("Bottom If");
      }
      //alert("FA Plus");            
      $(this).toggleClass('fa-plus');
      $(this).toggleClass('fa-minus');
      return false;
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: *«Right now both dropdown menus expand.»*
 -- Hew... Nope! : see [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/oGZBXN?editors=1011)

Comment: In mobile view, they both expand when clicking the plus icon in the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue that I was having.

Changed this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span.fa-plus").click(
    (function(e){
      if ($(".navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav li.dropdown").hasClass('menu-open')) {
        $(".navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav li.dropdown").removeClass('open');
        $(".navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav li.dropdown").removeClass('menu-open');
        $(".dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "true");  
        console.log("Top If");
      }
      else {
        $(".navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav li.dropdown").addClass('menu-open');
        $(".navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav li.dropdown").removeClass('open');
        $(".dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "false");  
        console.log("Bottom If");
      }
      //alert("FA Plus");            
      $(this).toggleClass('fa-plus');
      $(this).toggleClass('fa-minus');
      return false;
    })
  );
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span.fa-plus").click(
        (function(){
            if ($(this).parent().hasClass('menu-open')) 
                {
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('menu-open');
                    $(this).parent().find(".dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
                }
            else 
                {
                    //$(".navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav li.dropdown").addClass('menu-open');
                    $(this).parent().addClass('menu-open');
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
                    $(".dropdown.menu-open .dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
                }
            //alert("FA Plus");            
            $(this).toggleClass('fa-plus');
            $(this).toggleClass('fa-minus');
            return false;
        })
    );
});
```